# Jump Search time complexity worst case analysis

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, time-complexity

I have this jump search algorithm, and I have to analyze its time complexity in the worst case scenario

```
def find_me(search_object, array):
    n = len(array)
    lower = 0
    upper = n - 1
    while lower <= upper:
        idx = (lower + upper) // 2
        if search_object < array[idx]:
            upper = idx - 1
        elif search_object > array[idx]:
            lower = idx + 1
        else:
            return idx
    raise ValueError("Value is not in the list"
```

It looks to me as it has a O(n) linear complexity, as when I analyze the the steps:

3 x assignation
while loop  that runs n times
1 x n assignation
3 x n asignations

Comment: ´To me it looks like lg2 N, due to the range halving by idx.

Comment: This isn't jump search, it's binary search, and performs ceil(log_2(n)) comparisons in the worst case.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have misunderstood that!